# FLUTTER - How to obtain the GridView horizontal index?

Tags: flutter, indexing, gridview

I am developing a GridView in flutter. In every row I have 3 items. Every item is a widget that accepts a Color to be used as a background color.

What I want to achieve is to have the colors alternate, in this way

```
WHITE | BLACK | WHITE
BLACK | WHITE | BLACK
WHITE | BLACK | WHITE
```

The problem is that I don't know hot to get what is the index of every horizontal item. How to get this?

Comment: Could you provide the GridView code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code you get exact output like you describe

**Output :-**

[image]

**Code :-**

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
                ),
                itemCount: 9,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: 9,
  gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: (index % 2 == 0) ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Rs-234554',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Result-> [image]